# get the file which send by the multer in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, express, upload, multer

this is my upload.js code:

```js
var multer = require('multer');
var express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, 'uploads');
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now());
  },
});

var upload = multer({ storage: storage });

router.post('/', upload.single('file'), (req, res, next) => {
  const file = req.file;
  if (!file) {
    const error = new Error('Please upload a file');
    error.httpStatusCode = 400;
    return next(error);
  }
  res.send(file);
});

module.exports = router;
```

can anyone tell what will be the **router.get**? so that I can get an image in the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply [statically serve](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) the `uploads`-folder. By doing this you don't need an actual `get`-handler, instead you define the `express.static`-middleware

```
app.use(express.static('uploads'));
```

Now the client can simply perform a request to `http://yourServer/<imagename>-<timestamp>` and the file will be served automatically.

EDIT:

In order to get the generated file name to the client, you could do the following:

Instead of doing `res.send(file);` in your post-handler, you could return a json containing the generated filename, which the client then can request:

```
app.post("/upload", upload.single('image'), (req, res) => {
    res.json({uploadedFile: req.file.filename})
});
```

One more thing: you will lose the file's extension by with your `filename`-function. In order to keep the extension you could do (make sure to `require` the `path`-module):

```
filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    const extension = path.extname(file.originalname);
    cb(null, `${file.fieldname}-${Date.now()}${extension}`);
}
```

Comment: cay you tell me if I send a get request to the `/upload` in postman, how am I going to get the images in the uploads folder.? my code : [link](https://github.com/ishanajmeri/linkedin/tree/master/api-node)

Answer (score 0):

eol's answer is good, but if you need to maintain access, the controller might look something like this:

```
res.writeHead(200,{'content-type':'image/jpg'});
fs.createReadStream('./image/demo.jpg').pipe(res);
```